# Windows Raw Input works only if initialised late

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am creating a DLL which gets called from a Windows application. It calls my function which then spawns a thread running `PttThread` shown below. I then register a message only window to handle raw input events. None of the calls return any errors but I do not get raw input events. However, if I add a delay after creating the window but before registering the raw input it suddenly works.

Since Windows does not tell me anything is wrong, how can I change my code so initialisation works properly?

```
DWORD WINAPI PttThread(LPVOID lpParameter) {

    if (!hInstance) {
        hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    }

    //Create message only window
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.lpfnWndProc = messageProc;
    wx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wx.lpszClassName = class_name;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wx)) {
        printf("could not register window class: ");
        printLastError();
    }

    windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, class_name, L"R4nd0m_dummy_name", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!windowHandle) {
        printf("Could not create window\n");
        printLastError();
    }

    printf("hinstance %u\nhwnd %u\n", hInstance, windowHandle);

    // HERE
    Sleep(1000); //Then raw input works

    // Setup raw input
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[1];
    rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
    rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY | RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid[0].hwndTarget = windowHandle;
    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 1, sizeof(rid[0])) == FALSE) {
        printf("!!! Could not setup keyboard input\n");
        printLastError();
    }
    printf("Finish setup of PTT\n");

    // Raw input does NOT work if Sleep(1000) is move to here

    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Message received\n"); //Does not print if early registration of raw input.
        if (msg.message == MSG_SHUTDOWN) {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    threadShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702878/multiple-raw-input-window-sinks?rq=1 , and I noticed that if my raw input activates properly, the ALT-button does not work in the program anymore. If I disable my plugin it works again. Would this be because the application itself uses raw input? In that case is there anyway to create a "sub"-hInstance application handle that is all mine?

Comment: Do not create multiple UI-threads.

Comment: Assuming that `messageProc` is defined in your DLL, you are (potentially) passing the wrong module handle to your window class. I'm surprised this works at all. See [Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483) for a solution to this.

Comment: @Dieter I can not find any restrictions against this? I do not have access to the "real" ui-thread.

Comment: @IInspectable AFAICT , for windows the module handle is only really used to lookup (and store) where classes are registered.

Comment: I am not sure what alternatives are left? RegisterHotkey, but then I still need a "ui"-thread? From my reading, it sounds like only one system-wide hotkey can be active, which I understand as, another application can conflict with mine over control of the hotkey.   Maybe GetAsyncKeyState in a thread, but that does not seems completely reliable unless the application is foreground, and would require busy-looping which I want to avoid.

Comment: [WNDCLASSEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx): *"hInstance: A handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class."*

Comment: @IInspectable I see. I do not have a DllMain, but the dll still have an implicit handle? So maybe I could use that handle instead and avoid raw input conflict?

Comment: There is no such thing as an *"implicit handle"*. A module handle is the base address of the module in memory. That means that **any** module has a module handle.

Comment: @IInspectable I have now tried with both the "calling" handle and my dll handle, and both work. But I can see why using the wrong handle is wrong.